# Configure UML to generate core file

Tags: core-dump, user-mode-linux

The User Mode Linux (UML) I run on Ubuntu crashes occasionally, but does not generate any core file. I'd like to know the necessary configuration to be applied on UML so it generates a core when it crashes. Also, additional configuration which will ease the process of analyzing the core would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Setting 'ulimit -c unlimited' on the UML console generated the core for me. But this assumes that the UML was up long enough for this to be typed on the console, which was the case for me.